# Is mikrotik home setup questions off topic for network engineering?

Tags: discussion

I would like to get help on setting up routing via two ISP provided ports on Mikrotik RouterOS. That is to route IPTV traffic to one port and Internet - to another. If I ask question describing my current setup and the problems I have with it, will it be considered an off topic for stack exchange network engineering? If yes, where could I ask such questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Home networking questions are explicitly off topic here, as is described in the [Help Center](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help). This question is on-topic on the [Super User](https://superuser.com) Stack Exchange.

Comment: Plenty of people have more complex network at home than some branch enterprise/SMB setup. I would say it is totally on topic if you talking about  BGP, multicast, IPsec, WLC etc...

Comment: The community decided that two the requirements are (a) "[the equipment is] under your direct control " and (b)"hardware that has a paid support option (enterprise/provider class products, some small business class devices);". Mikrotik doesn't provide support, and many home networks contain devices which are managed by the ISP. I do however agree that there is a gray area when it would be a specific question about configuring BGP. However, I don't think this community would immediately vote to close a question like that if it's properly worded.

Comment: There are plenty of consulting services that support MikroTik. And many service providers do use Mikrotik especially at the edge. Direct control can be very subjective. A single device can be managed by several parties. I have seen plenty of times certain people vote close questions right away because it does not fit their taste.